# Rails 4 subdomains does not work on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, subdomain, passenger

I've created an Rails 4 application with 3 sub-domains.

Development domains:

- mydomain.dev
- api.mydomain.dev
- account.mydomain.dev

Production domains (Ngnix with Passenger):

- app.mydomain.com (www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com show other page, not the application)
- api.mydomain.com
- account.mydomain.com

My config/routes.rb looks like that:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/', defaults: { format: :json } do
        namespace :v1 do
            resources :clients, only: [:create, :show]
        end
    end

    namespace :account, constraints: { subdomain: 'account' }, path: '/' do
        get '/:locale' => 'welcome#index', locale: /en|pt/
        root 'welcome#index'

        scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|pt/ do
            get :sign_in, to: 'sessions#new'
            post :sign_in, to: 'sessions#create'
        end
    end

    get '/:locale' => 'welcome#index', locale: /en|pt/
    root 'welcome#index'

    scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|pt/ do
        resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
        get :login, to: 'sessions#new', as: :login
    end
end
```

My ngnix virtual host file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name mydomain.com api.mydomain.com account.mydomain.com;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myapp/wrappers/ruby;

    root /var/sites/mydomain.com/current/public;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com/server.key;
}
```

The problem, is that on my dev machine (localhost) or development environment its works very well, as I want. But on production I got the error: "`The page you were looking for doesn't exist.`", with this log info:

Visiting: https://account.mydomain.com/en/sign_in

> I, [2015-07-29T11:31:07.197635 #25813]  INFO -- : Started GET
>   "/en/sign_in" for 0.0.0.0 at 2015-07-29 11:31:07 +0100 F,
>   [2015-07-29T11:31:07.206758 #25813] FATAL -- :
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/en/sign_in"):
>   actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
>
>   newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>
>   newrelic_rpm (3.12.1.298)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'   railties
>   (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'

in other works, account.mydomain.com and api.mydomain.com still acting as my main domain "mydomain.com" (as the same domain).

UPDATE:

I add this code on my page:

```
<%= request.domain.inspect %><br>
<%= request.subdomain.inspect %>
```

Visiting: http://api.mydomain.co.ao 
As Result I got:

> As Domain: "co.ao"
>
> As Subdomain: "api.mydomain"

But my subdomain here is only: api

What is wrong?

Comment: have you set config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/approot"
in your environment.rb?

Comment: @PierangeloOrizio thanks for your comment. I am using Rails 4.2.3, and as I see, relative_url_root was deprecated: ```This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v2.1.0) is shown here.```- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/AbstractRequest/relative_url_root

Comment: ok, sorry... do you use some .htaccess and fastcgi, because if is so you need to remove the previous FastCGI mod_rewrite lines in your .htaccess.

Comment: @PierangeloOrizio I am using Nginx 1.8.0 With passenger 5.0.11

Comment: @PierangeloOrizio see my update please

Comment: by default tld_length = 1, try giving tld_length=2.
`config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2` in production.rb

Comment: Hi @PardeepDhingra first I used a regex expression that solved the problem. But now seeing your comment I think that that is the best way. Thanks its working

Comment: Great..@P.Santos..I am adding it as answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Default

```
tld_length = 1
```

You need to update tld_length to 2 for domain like: co.in, co.au

Try:

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2
```

in config/enviroments/production.rb

[Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Request/domain)