# Rails Subdomain in Host Being Replaced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the following `config/routes.rb`:

```
constraints subdomain: 'subdomain' do
  get 'path', to: 'main#index', as: :sample
end
```

The following works:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sample_url(host: "a.b")
# "http://subdomain.a.b/path"
```

The following fails:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sample_url(host: "a.b.c")
# "http://subdomain.b.c/path"
```

Any way to fix it so subdomains don't replace existing subdomains in the host but instead are linked (i.e. `http://subdomain.a.b.c/path`)? I realize I can change the subdomain in the route to be `subdomain.a` - but that'd be a bit of a pain to maintain for multiple subdomains / deployments.

Comment: As a note, if you're calling subdomains you can use the `_url` helpers rather than `_path`. EG `sample_url(:args)` -- will save calling `Rails.application.routes...`

Comment: @RichardPeck yup - but you need to prefix with `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` if you are calling from the console. Note the example is using the `_url` helpers.

Comment: Yes of course, I didn't realize you were doing it from cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to examine [`tld_length`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for):

> `:tld_length` - Number of labels the TLD id composed of, only used if
>   `:subdomain` or `:domain` are supplied. Defaults to
>   ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length, which in turn defaults to 1.

I'll test the specifics, but the issue looks like Rails is only allowing a `tld` (top level domain) length of 1, which means that you can only have a subdomain and 1 "other" element (`subdomain.b.c` / `subdomain.a.b`).

The fix should be to expand the `tld_length`, which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31702767/1143732), can be done in the config settings `/config/application.rb`:

```
# config/application.rb
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2
```

---

Tests

Without `tld_length`:

```
c:\Dev\Apps\torches>rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sample_url(host: "a.b")
=> "http://subdomain.a.b/path"
irb(main):002:0> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sample_url(host: "a.b.c")
=> "http://subdomain.b.c/path"
irb(main):003:0>
```

With `tld_length`:

```
c:\Dev\Apps\torches>rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sample_url(host: "a.b")
=> "http://subdomain.a.b/path"
irb(main):002:0> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sample_url(host: "a.b.c")
=> "http://subdomain.a.b.c/path"
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

create config/initializers/host_name.rb file, where you can place a constant :

```
HOST_NAME = 'b.c'
```

then anywhere in your code :

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.sample_url(host: HOST_NAME, subdomain: 'subdomain.a')
```

you can also create constants for your subdomains if you like