# Getting Forward to play nice with pow and subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forward, pow

I have a Rails app `foobar` with various subdomains set up, for example, `admin`. I use `pow` to test the app locally, and things work just fine: `admin.foobar.test/users` correctly routes to `Admin::UsersController`.

However, when trying to get it to work with Forward, I can only get it to point to the top level namespace. It doesn't matter whether I do `forward admin.foobar.test`, `forward foobar.test`, or `forward test`, in all cases, `foobar.fwd.wf/users` and `admin.foobard.fwd.wf/users` raise 404s because it's trying to find the `/users` route at the top level, rather than within the `admin` namespace.

The workaround I have for now is redefining my subdomain routes at the top level, but that is obviously a quick hack, not a viable long term fix.

I've already read https://forwardhq.com/announcements/05-forward-now-supports-wildcard-subdomains. It does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on this question: [Rails 4 subdomains does not work on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698032/rails-4-subdomains-does-not-work-on-production)

The default TLD length is 1, but when using Forward, the TLD is `.fwd.wf`. The fix is therefore to add the following to `development.rb`:

```rb
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2
```

Comment: And of course I find the answer on my own right after asking on SO, after being stuck on it for hours...